# Graphical Bootloaders?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, bootloader

I am currently using Ubuntu LTS 14.04 and I am curious about various graphical bootloaders. I have heard of them, such as BURG, GAG, Chameleon, Chimera, etc. However, they (GAG and BURG because I don't have OS X) aren't what I want and designing a theme for BURG is random and all over the place when it comes to tutorials, so my main questions are

1. Is it possible to use Chameleon or Chimera without OS X? If so, where can I find out how to this?
2. Is there another bootloader that has many themes and icons for various OSes (Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows XP, Ubuntu, Arch Linux, Bodhi Linux, etc.)?
3. Is it possible to make a bootloader like the picture in the link below (excluding the internet option)? If so, how hard would it be to program?

Picture:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at rEFInd. It is the fork/update to refit. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ It works with Mac & now other UEFI based systems. It is not a boot loader, but a boot manager or menu system.

Comment: Is it possible to change the appearence of it?

Comment: Did you review the rEFInd site? I do not use it, but found this in a few seconds. http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/themes.html

Comment: Thanks for the help oldfred. In case I don't have UEFI or EFI, does anyone know one that would work for basic BIOS?

Comment: Unfortunately from what I have read on this topic, EFI it's a must requirement.