# Customize Dual-Boot?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, windows-10

Can we customize the look and feel of dual-boot? For example, make the screen more modern instead of a black screen with white text. Note that I am completely new to Linux (including Ubuntu) and I would like to start compiling my own Android kernels and code, of course. I hate so much the look of the dual-boot screen and I would really appreciate if someone helps me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can hide the dual boot screen (grub) and have it go straight into Ubuntu. The times you want to see the menu you press the shift key on boot. That said you can use custom background images, high res fonts, animated boot images and custom login screen images but this takes sometime to learn (googling is best method) and setup.

Comment: Did you want to compile **Android** or **Linux** kernels? For being *new* to Ubuntu, I'd suggest that you learn Unity, Ubuntu, and the command line interface, long before digging into the very complicated kernel compiles.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you'll want to read my solution in http://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the for hiding the GRUB menu in dual-boot configurations. Vote it up, if you like :-)

Comment: I wasn't the one with grub questions... My system is already highly modified... :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have Grub as bootloader you can check this Question: [How do I customize the GRUB 2 menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/532238/37213)

Otherwise you can check [BURG](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Burg)

Here a list of [Bootloaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders)

Last but not least check this question [Graphical Bootloaders?](https://askubuntu.com/q/550483/37213)

Comment: Apparantly BURG doesn't properly support UEFI machines (although some folks say they've got it running on UEFI machines). rEFInd might be a good substitute.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding my question! I am truly sorry for the super late reply. I forgot to mention that I'm new to this forum too and I just saw the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I know there is an answer here already, but you can use Grub customizer from the ubuntu software store. I use it for my dual boot and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

### Grub Themes

You can use grub-themes which comes standard on every Ubuntu installation:

[image: Grub Boot]

---

### Make Grub fonts

Even if you are just using regular grub, if you want a different font you must use `grub-mkfont` program first. The same holds true for Grub Customizer used by OP and Grub Themes used in first section of this answer.

Here are the fonts I have made for grub to use:

```
$ ll /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/*.pf2
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 176923 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/dejavu_14.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  20041 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_bold_17.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  23339 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_bold_20.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  31498 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_bold_26.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  15244 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_regular_12.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  19148 Jun  9 16:41 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/droidlogo_regular_17.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root 113623 Jul 11 17:05 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_bold_italic_36.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  45391 Jul 11 17:08 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_light_20.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  41020 Jul 11 17:16 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_regular_18.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  46423 Jul 11 17:16 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_regular_20.pf2*
-rwxrwx--- 1 root root  68602 Jul 11 16:59 /usr/share/grub/themes/Tuxkiller2/ubuntu_regular_28.pf2*
```

To create a font use the `grub-mkfont` program like this guide outlines: [Increase Font in GRUB for High DPI Screens](http://blog.wxm.be/2014/08/29/increase-font-in-grub-for-high-dpi.html):

```
sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2 \
  --size=24 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

Then in your `/etc/default/grub` configuration file tell it to use the new `.pf2` font file:

```
# More readable font on high dpi screen, generated with
# sudo grub-mkfont --output=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2 \
#    --size=24 /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSansMono24.pf2
```

Finally run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

Grub themes are built into grub so use:

```
$ apt policy grub2-common
grub2-common:
  Installed: 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18
  Candidate: 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18
  Version table:
 *** 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.18 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```